# mediaplayer doent contain a constructor that takes 0 argument - UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, media-player, uwp-xaml

I'm using a very simple example to play media using MediaPlayer class in UWP application. But I'm getting an error when calling its constructor.

```
MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); // error over here
_mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/example_video.mkv"));
_mediaPlayer.Play();
```

error is : MediaPlayer doent contain a constructor that takes 0 argument

what has gone wrong?

Comment: Are you using `System.Windows.Media`?  Or perhaps you have the wrong reference?

Comment: using Windows.Media.Playback; @LukeSamuel

Comment: That class has a default constructor.  The only reason for giving that error is if the compiler is matching it to some other `MediaPlayer` class.

Answer (score 0):

You replace contructor like below:

```
MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer = BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current;
_mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/example_video.mkv"));
_mediaPlayer.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably targetting an older UWP version. As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer#Windows_Media_Playback_MediaPlayer__ctor), `MediaPlayer()` was introduced in the Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (introduced v10.0.14393.0). Even the latest [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer) talk about using the constructor.

**After Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (v10.0.14393.0):**

```
MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

**Before Windows 10 Anniversary Edition:**

```
MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer = BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current;
```